# jQuery bug in Chrome with form submission disabling

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
$('#continue').click(function() {
   $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

This disables the submit button and it works in Firefox and IE. But it doesn't work in Chrome or most likely Safari.

EDIT:  I want the button reenabled when a particular link is clicked.  I have this:

```
$("#continue").removeAttr("disabled");
```

but it doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: bug is filed for IE not chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YEZS7/

Comment: I wasn't clear.  I want the button disabled until the user clicks on a particular link.

Comment: If I want to add an ID to the submit input, what's the syntax for that?

Comment: Change our HTML to `<input type="submit" id="my_submit "val="Submit" />` and in our code change `$('input[type="submit"]')` to `$('#my_submit')`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to disable the submit button if the user clicks on another element, or is #continue the submit button? Because in this case, you just need to return false in your click-function.

```
$('#continue').click(function() {
   return false;
});
```